# When use rabbitmq.conf and rabbitmq-env.conf?

Tags: rabbitmq

I am reading:

- [RabbitMQ Configuration](https://www.rabbitmq.com/configure.html)

What is not clear is

- When use `rabbitmq.conf` and `rabbitmq-env.conf`?

Especially when is mandatory use one over the other, it without matter in what OS (Windows, Linux, Mac) RabbitMQ is running.

Answer (score 1):

I'm on linux and I use both.

In my system `rabbitmq` comes with pre-configured `rabbitmq-env.conf`. It would probably be enough if I was not clustering across multiple hosts (there is no `rabbitmq.conf` added to my `/etc/rabbitmq` by default).

As far as I understand (and I'm not `rabbitmq` expert) the `rabbitmq.conf` is to control some `erlang` based options. I personally use kernel options to bind rabbitmq to interface of my choice. But there is myriad of other things you can do there - in example you can configure rabbitmq to communicate over `ssl` and require all clients to authenticate using specific fields in their certificates. As far as I understand you cannot do that by using `rabbitmq-env.conf`.

Answer (score 1):

`rabbitmq-env.conf` is used to set environment variables that are read upon startup [docs](https://www.rabbitmq.com/configure.html#customise-environment). `rabbitmq.conf` is used to set things like TCP port, SSL certificates [docs](https://www.rabbitmq.com/configure.html#configuration-files).

Environment variables (specified via `rabbitmq-env.conf`) are generally used to configure values that must be set prior to the start of the Erlang virtual machine - things like node name, the location of log and database files, etc.